# How to just print the binary code of a function in an object file?

Tags: macos, object, disassembly, objdump, otool

I am able to disassemble an object file like below. But I'd like to just dump the raw number like 55, 48, ... of instructions in a binary format for a specific function, e.g., add4, to a file.

I could write a program to parse the output of otool. But is there an easier way to do so?

My OS is Mac OS X.

```
$ cat add.c
long x;
long add2(long num) {
  return num + 2;
}
long add4(long num) {
  return num + 4;
}
$ clang -c -o add.o add.c
$ otool -tvjV add.o 
add.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_add4:
0000000000000000    55  pushq   %rbp
0000000000000001    48 89 e5    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000000000004    48 89 7d f8     movq    %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
0000000000000008    48 8b 7d f8     movq    -0x8(%rbp), %rdi
000000000000000c    48 83 c7 04     addq    $0x4, %rdi
0000000000000010    48 89 f8    movq    %rdi, %rax
0000000000000013    5d  popq    %rbp
0000000000000014    c3  retq
0000000000000015    66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00   nopw    %cs:_add4(%rax,%rax)
000000000000001f    90  nop
_add2:
0000000000000020    55  pushq   %rbp
0000000000000021    48 89 e5    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000000000024    48 89 7d f8     movq    %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
0000000000000028    48 8b 7d f8     movq    -0x8(%rbp), %rdi
000000000000002c    48 83 c7 02     addq    $0x2, %rdi
0000000000000030    48 89 f8    movq    %rdi, %rax
0000000000000033    5d  popq    %rbp
0000000000000034    c3  retq
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nm -nU add.o` to get the symbol addresses. You can search for the symbol of interest and get its address and the subsequent address. That gives you the start and (roughly) length of the symbol. Then, you can use any tool for hex dumping from a file to read just that portion.

For example:

```
exec 3< <(nm -nU add.o | grep -A1 -w _add4 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
read start <&3
read end <&3
3<&-
offset=$(otool -lV add.o | grep -A3 -w "segname __TEXT" | grep -m1 offset | cut -c 12-)
if [ -n "$end" ] ; then length_arg="-n $(( "0x$end" - "0x$start" ))" ; fi
hexdump -C -s $((0x$start + $offset)) $length_arg add.o
```

Comment: What if the symbol is the last one (e.g., _add2)?

Comment: Well, it may be the last symbol in the `__TEXT,__text` section, but there's probably a symbol in a subsequent section. You can just leave off the `-n <length>` option to `hexdump` if reading `end` failed. That will dump to the end of the file.

Comment: No. hexdump just fails. Here is the output. ```$ eval `nm -nU add.o | grep -A1 _add2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | \
    (read start ; read end ; echo "hexdump -C -s 0x$start -n" $(( "0x$end" - "0x$start" )) add.o )`
hexdump: -32: bad length value ```

Comment: I don't think the result is correct. The first character in the result is 0xcf. But it should be 55. ```eval `nm -nU add.o | grep -A1 _add4 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | \
>     (read start ; read end ; echo "hexdump -C -s 0x$start -n" $(( "0x$end" - "0x$start" )) add.o )`
00000000  cf fa ed fe 07 00 00 01  03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  04 00 00 00 b0 01 00 00  00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00  |......... ......|
00000020
```

Comment: Hmm. `cf fa ed fe` is the magic for a 64-bit Mach-O object. Is your object file universal/fat?

Comment: I don't know. How to check?

Comment: Note that I have a global variable `x`. I have updated the example.

Comment: Ah, I neglected the fact that, for object files, the `__TEXT` segment doesn't necessarily start at the beginning of the file. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use objdump and then extract the opcode part. It can be done as follows.

`$ objdump -d add.o  | grep add4 -A10 | cut -f 2 | grep -v ':'`

The -v flag for grep tells it to print all lines not containing a colon.

Output:

```
    55                   
    48 89 e5             
    48 89 7d f8          
    48 8b 45 f8          
    48 83 c0 04          
    5d                
    c3
```

The -A10 tells grep to print 10 lines after the match.

Now to output this into a file, we first format the opcodes as hex like '\x45'.
The above output can have multiple spaces and a space at the end of each line, so we remove them first as it can mess with our sed.

`$ objdump -d add.o  | grep add4 -A10 | cut -f 2 | grep -v ':' | sed 's/  */ /g' | sed 's/ $//g'`

Add the '\x' part, first for the spaces in between and then for the first hex in each line.

`$ objdump -d add.o  | grep add4 -A10 | cut -f 2 | grep -v ':' | sed 's/  */ /g' | sed 's/ $//g' | sed 's/ /\\x/g' | sed 's/^/\\x/g'`

```
\x55
\x48\x89\xe5
\x48\x89\x7d\xf8
\x48\x8b\x45\xf8
\x48\x83\xc0\x04
\x5d
\xc3
```

Collapse it all into a single line and add quotes.

`$ objdump -d add.o  | grep add4 -A10 | cut -f 2 | grep -v ':' | sed 's/  */ /g' | sed 's/ $//g' | sed 's/ /\\x/g' | sed 's/^/\\x/g' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/^/\"/g' | sed 's/$/\"/g'`

```
"\x55\x48\x89\xe5\x48\x89\x7d\xf8\x48\x8b\x45\xf8\x48\x83\xc0\x04\x5d\xc3"
```

Now we got a C-style string and we just pass it to printf and then redirect the output to a file.

`$ printf $(objdump -d add.o  | grep add4 -A10 | cut -f 2 | grep -v ':' | sed 's/  */ /g' | sed 's/ $//g' | sed 's/ /\\x/g' | sed 's/^/\\x/g' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/^/\"/g' | sed 's/$/\"/g') | sed 's/^\"//g' | sed 's/\"$//g' > add4.bin`

The last two seds after the printf are to remove the quotes which remains in printf's output for some reason.

Hexdumping the file we get:

`$ hexdump -C add4.bin`

```
00000000  55 48 89 e5 48 89 7d f8  48 8b 45 f8 48 83 c0 04  |UH..H.}.H.E.H...|
00000010  5d c3                                             |].|
00000012
```